# How can I get Google Fit Client state?

Tags: android, google-fit

At some devices, I get data once in an hour! But at another, I get them every 4 minutes.
I make client:

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
        .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
        .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_ACTIVITY_READ)
        .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_BODY_READ_WRITE)
        .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_LOCATION_READ_WRITE)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
        .addConnectionCallbacks(Client.this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(Client.this)
        .build();

client.connect();
```

Then sensor:

```
  Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
                client,
                new SensorRequest.Builder()
                        .setDataSource(dataSource)
                        .setDataType(dataType)
                        .setAccuracyMode(SensorRequest.ACCURACY_MODE_HIGH)
                        .setSamplingRate(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setFastestRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setMaxDeliveryLatency(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build(),
                mListener)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d("stepsCount", "Listener registered!");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("stepsCount", "Listener not registered.");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And then I want to check client state, but I don't know how (

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the state with the callback given in the [document](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started):

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    if (mClient == null && checkPermissions()) {
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                findFitnessDataSources();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                if (i == ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                } else if (i
                                        == ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                result.toString());
                        Snackbar.make(
                                MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                                "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " +
                                        result.getErrorMessage(),
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now for some information on how to show the data in your app in real time, using the Sensors API together with the Recording API.

- [DevBytes: Google Fit APIs for Android - Setup and Sensors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwaQaWGLlTo)
- [DevBytes: Google Fit APIs for Android - Recording and History](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS8OLV-D1lw)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't always check the state with the callback. I need to check state any moment.